# Replace first part of nginx $uri before proxy_pass

Tags: http, nginx, web, curl

I have following location ngix config:

```
  location /bar {
    proxy_pass http://bar-api/api; 
  }
```

I can test it with curl

```
$ curl foo.com/bar/test
{"test passed":true}
```

But IP address of internal server **bar-api** could change, so I can not specify it directly as above.

I understand, I need to use variables in the location block and specify resolver. Resolver is already specified in http block of nginx config `resolver 192.168.0.11 valid=10s;`

I'm not sure how to modify location block, so it will work the same way as before.
I tried this:

```
  location /bar {
    set $target http://bar-api/api;
    proxy_pass $target; 
  }
```

But test fails:

```
$ curl foo.com/bar/test  
<getting 404>
```

Also tried:

```
  location /bar {
    set $target bar-api;
    proxy_pass http://$target/api; 
  }
```

Test still fails:

```
$ curl foo.com/bar/test  
<getting 404>
```

Probably `$uri` should be modified with regex. This part `/bar/test` should be `/api/test`
So I could use it in location.

```
  location /bar {
    set $target bar-api;
    <some magic here>
    proxy_pass http://$target/$modified_uri; 
  }
```

But how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Use `rewrite...break` to make the URI change. For example:

```
location /bar {
    set $target bar-api;
    rewrite ^/bar(.*)$ /api$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://$target;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

Comment: Thank you. It works, last line should be "proxy_pass http://$target/api$uri;" in my case.

Comment: Oops, I've updated my answer. The idea of the `rewrite...break` is to avoid using the `proxy_pass` statement to modify the URI.